# Plotting financial/investment values over time

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, time-series, finance

I am trying to compute the TPVI [(current value+dividends)/invested] over time of several companies in a dataframe.

My dataframe looks like this (dates in this example are not exact)

| Company | Date | Metric | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company1 | 11-15-2015 | invested | 100 |
| Company1 | 11-15-2015 | current value | 120 |
| Company1 | 11-15-2015 | dividends | 5 |
| Company2 | 11-15-2015 | invested | 200 |
| Company2 | 11-15-2015 | current value | 120 |
| Company2 | 11-15-2015 | dividends | 30 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I am trying to sort the values into a new dataframe that will look like this:

| Company | Date | TVPI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Company1 | ... | ... |
| Company1 | ... | ... |
| Company1 | ... | ... |
| Company1 | ... | ... |
| Company2 | ... | ... |
| Company2 | ... | ... |
| Company2 | ... | ... |

i.e. a new TVPI row for each unique company/date pairing.

I have tried

`df %>% group_by(Date, Metric) %>% summarize()`

but I am not sure how to identify the proper values to summarize (in the example dataframe, the first tpvi would be (120+5)/100. Since each company/date pairing has three "values" to keep track of, the syntax of how to word this in a `summarize` function eludes me. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to easily perform calculations on the different `Metric`s is to fist `tidyr::pivot_wider()` so they're each a separate column and then use your formula to make a new column with `dplyr::mutate()`. If you also supply `.keep = "unused"` to `mutate()` it will leave just the columns you indicated in your desired output. Also I convert your `Date` column to an actual `date` format instead of a `character` which will make it behave better as an `x` axis value in the plot. Then you can go directly into plotting. The example is pretty boring because you only supplied one `Date` per `Company` but this shows the general idea.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- structure(list(Company = c("Company1", "Company1", "Company1", "Company2", "Company2", "Company2"), Date = c("11-15-2015", "11-15-2015", "11-15-2015", "11-15-2015", "11-15-2015", "11-15-2015"), Metric = c("invested", "current value", "dividends", "invested", "current value", "dividends"), Value = c(100L, 120L, 5L, 200L, 120L, 30L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

d %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Metric, values_from = Value) %>% 
  mutate(TPVI = (`current value` + dividends)/invested, .keep = "unused",
         Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%m-%d-%Y")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Date, TPVI, color = Company)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>